# Why do kernel updates on Manjaro change my network MAC address?

Tags: linux, manjaro, software-updates, mac-address

I've configured NAS access based on client IP address.

It's now the third time that I've updated the kernel on my Manjaro installation, and each time I get booted off the NAS. Why? Because my workstation doesn't receive the expected IP address from the DHCP server. Why? Because the network card's MAC address has changed. Why? I really have no idea. Help!

This does not happen when I merely update packages (installed applications, etc.).

Please explain to me (a) the logic behind the MAC address being affected by OS updates, and (b) what I can do to stop it (preemptively: configuring NAS access differently is a good suggestion, but off-topic for this particular post).

**EDIT:** To combat close votes, here's more info:

```
$ ifconfig | grep ether -B 3
wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.113  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::6d0e:1c71:9ab9:28c7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 42:ec:44:93:8c:4b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

and I note that the MAC address specified here has changed, most recently from `00:23:14:b0:11:f8` to `42:ec:44:93:8c:4b` when I upgraded to kernel "Linux 4.14.133-1" (from "Linux 4.9.185-1").

**EDIT 2:** I don't use MAC spoofing *on purpose* (if I had it would be something akin to `1337deadbeef`); this is a pretty straightforward installation (my first Manjaro install). How would I go about checking/confirming/changing that?

**EDIT 3:** I've checked the page [linked](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing) to by @muru, which suggests several methods:

- `$ macchanger
  bash: macchanger: command not found`
- `$ cat /etc/systemd/network/00-default.link
  cat: /etc/systemd/network/00-default.link: No such file or directory
  $ ll /etc/systemd/network/
  total 0`
- `$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/75-mac-spoof.rules
  cat: /etc/udev/rules.d/75-mac-spoof.rules: No such file or directory
  $ ll /etc/udev/rules.d/
  total 0`
- `$ cat /etc/systemd/system/macspoof@.service
  cat: /etc/systemd/system/macspoof@.service: No such file or directory`
- `$ ll /etc/netctl/interfaces/
  total 0`

and also from the [NetworkManager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Configuring_MAC_address_randomization) page:

- `$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/wifi_rand_mac.conf
  cat: /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/wifi_rand_mac.conf: No such file or directory
  $ ll /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/
  total 0`

So it seems that there is no MAC spoofing going on, but somehow the MAC address still changes on kernel updates. Is this behaviour in any way expected or heard of?

Comment: Hey, those of you voting to close because "it's unclear what I'm asking" -- please COMMENT so that I can improve my question! I don't get notifications of close votes, and had no idea of this. So what more, specifically, do you want to know?

Comment: You probably have mac spoofing configured somewhere.

Comment: There are plenty of methods to spoof mac addresses: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing see if any of them is enabled anywhere in your system.